# What is this error? This function is not registered in the lock list

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui, monaca

This is the error msg.

```
Error: This function is not registered in the lock list.
    at Object.window.DoorLock.DoorLock._unlock (loader.js:1450)
    at window.DoorLock.DoorLock.lock.unlock (loader.js:1450)
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$broadcast (loader.js:1444)
```

...

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-csp>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/winstore-jscompat.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesshet" href="components/monaca-onsenui/js/angular/angular-csp.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src = "./js/prog.js" ></script>
</head>
<body ng-app = "magic_land" >
    <ons-navigator var="captain" page="list.html">
    </ons-navigator> 
</body>
</html>
```

...

```
list.html

<div >

  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class = "center">All todoz</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item>Apple</ons-list-item> 
    <ons-list-item>Banana</ons-list-item> 
    <ons-list-item>Carrot</ons-list-item> 

  </ons-list>

  <p> {{5+5}}  </p>

</div>
```

...

```
prog.js


        var magic_land = ons.bootstrap('magic_land', ['onsen']);
```

Where is this error coming from?

Comment: `Where is this error coming from?` - javascript, and it's not the **single line** of javascript you posted that's causing the error

Comment: @Armadeus the code you posted seems ok, I tried to create a CodePen sample ([LINK](http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/MaaRJq)) and it seems working fine. That means that the problem is somewhere else, maybe in the paths

Comment: thanks @andi-pavllo !

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
<body ng-app="magic_land" ng-controller = "magic_action">
    <ons-navigator var="captain" page="list.html"   >
    </ons-navigator> 
</body>
```

After

```
<body >
    <ons-navigator var="captain" page="list.html" ng-app="magic_land" ng-controller = "magic_action"  >
    </ons-navigator> 
</body>
```

Now that error is gone! 
I know, this code is different from the question , but it was a tough error so i had to swap and rearrange my codes to find the source of error. 
 Good luck!

Comment: My files are index.html, edit.html, list.html, and prog.js . Not easy.